# What is using connection in the code

Tags: c#-2.0

What is the purpose of `using (connection)` in the code - please explain me

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)/// what is this line 
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, HasRows doesn't seem like a very good name for this function...

Answer (score 6):

```
using (connection){
    connection.Open();
}
```

makes sure that `connection` is closed when the application is done using it.
similar to a `Try Catch`.

```
try{
    connection.Open();
}
catch{
}
finally{
    connection.Dispose(); 
}
```

Disposing of the connection is another way of saying closing a connection.  An open connection can leak memory and if you have too many it can slow down or freeze up whatever you are connecting to.

the `using` function closes the connection even after you return something from the class you are in. same as the `try catch`.  it always closes the connection no matter what happens inside the brackets. even if there is an exception that breaks out of the class/application the connection still gets closed

Comment: What is here meaning of dispoing an object it will free the memory of object or will simply release it and object will be still in memory and will be collected by GC. and what is the use to dispose the object like in DB connection, connection obeject will call the connection.Dispose then what it exactly do what resource it is  relaeasing

Comment: in general want to know what happens all other object which don't use dispose methods, even if they dont hold the any unmanaged resource how they get closed bcas i dont close them externally, is it GC take care of them?

Answer (score 5):

[Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)

Quote from site:

The `using` statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that use resources should release them. The object provided to the using statement must implement the `IDisposable` interface. This interface provides the `Dispose` method, which should release the object's resources.

Comment: "Using" should have been used with the SQLCommand and SQLDataReader variables as well.

Comment: we don't need to explicitly close the dataadapter connection? abd also what is equivalent of this  using (connection)

Comment: All of the closing and disposing is handle by the using statement so it's less code for you, and a more robust way to make sure you're cleaning up any finished with resources.

Comment: see i red that database connection is an managed resource so if i hold the connection like this  _connectString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
_sqlCon = new SqlConnection(_connectString); and then if i use it in my code like this using(_sqlCon) so _sqlCon i need to explicitely close and it will free the memory for that database object hold by it...is it correct also i am wary about one thing that what is this dataBase object resource and dispose method release the object only o also memory of it too

Answer (score 2):

I would probably re-write the method to something like the following:

```
static void HasRows(string connectionString)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
        connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                        reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your original implementation the caller could be at the receiving end of an `ObjectDisposedException` exception, because the SqlConnection is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: what is the equivalent of your above code in try catch and finally form

Comment: using the above code we don't have to explicitly close the data base connection is it true?

Comment: that is i don't need to write the connection.close(), so what about any other kind of object that we create like data table object, i dont close it and even dotn call a dispose mehod on it well it dotn hold any unmanged resource, but should still do the dt.close(); where dt is ata table object or this object will be closed by GC

Comment: When an application is finished the compiler should release all data objects and variables.  the Data Object (data table) will be alive as long as it is in scope of the application.