# calculating the average of field entries

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to calculate the average of some int entries in a database table using a basic ado.net procedure but get an error that states that the cast is not valid.

```
try
        {
            int average;

            string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                               Data Source=BookRateInitial.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);



            OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT AVG(rating) FROM bookRated WHERE title = 'the informers'";

            connection.Open();
            average = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            Console.WriteLine("The average is thus {0}", average);
            connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
```

Is this the correct way of calculating the average of a set of entries in a database?.

Kind regards

Comment: What type of exception do you get. What happens when you run the query direct on the database? You also have a connection leak. Put the connection close in the finally or use "using" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085466/what-is-using-connection-in-the-code). I also recommend to use a stored procedure instead of putting the query in code

Comment: The error is probably because your average has decimal places, so it can't convert to an int.  You need to either round it to no decimal places, or truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if (! (result is DBNull))
 {
    average = Convert.ToInt32(result);
 }
```

BTW, shouldn't average be float / double ?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
average = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

with:

```
Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
     average  = Reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try cast/convert to decimal. ;)

something like this

```
try { return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); }
catch (Exception) { throw; }
```

Comment: A general catch clause is very bad practice. At least catch a specific exception (InvalidCastException).

Answer (score 0):

The error message says what's wrong. Either the result is DBNull or it is not an Int32. If you're sure about the result type being an Int32, use this:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
average = result != DBNull.Value ? (int) result : 0;
```